# JQ add properties to nested object in nested array

Tags: json, jq

I have the following json:

```
{
  "first": {
    "second" : "A"
  },
  "array": [
    {
      "name" : "AAA",
      "something": {
        "hola": "hi"
      }
    },
    {
      "name" : "BBB",
      "something": {
        "hola": "hi"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to trasform it adding a property to the `something` object, using the value from the `name` property of the parent, like:

I have the following json:

```
{
  "first": {
    "second" : "A"
  },
  "array": [
    {
      "name" : "AAA",
      "something": {
        "hola": "hi",
        "NEW_PROPERTY": "AAA"
      }
    },
    {
      "name" : "BBB",
      "something": {
        "hola": "hi",
        "NEW_PROPERTY": "BBB"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Which jq expression can do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this jq script:

```
<file jq '.array = [ .array[] | .something.NEW_PROPERTY = .name ]'
```

This is replacing the `array` by another one that is the same as the original one with one more key `NEW_PROPERTY`.

Comment: Nice! I was missing the final piece to add the `.name` field.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use the filter:

```
.array |= map(.something.NEW_PROPERTY = .name)
```

or if `map`'s not your thing (or if you want to save typing one character):

```
.array[] |= (.something.NEW_PROPERTY = .name)
```